# Definition of rate of convergence for a sequence of measurable mappings

Tags: probability, reference-request, statistics, measure-theory

If a sequence of measurable mappings defined from a measure spaces to another measure space converges in different modes (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) and [John Cook's site](http://www.johndcook.com/modes_of_convergence.html)), I wonder if there are some concepts capturing their rates of convergence for different modes of convergence?

You may restrict the discussion to probability theory.
One example is in statistics. Suppose $\theta_n$ is an estimator for $\theta^*$ based on a sample with sample size $n$. I was wondering how the rate of convergence of $\theta_n$ is defined?

I also appreciate if there can be some references offered.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: [Modes of convergence](http://www.johndcook.com/modes_of_convergence.html)

Comment: Thanks! How about rate of convergence?

Answer (score 1):

There is a paper that I do not have access to that you might find relevant: Davis, R.A. (1982). The rate of convergence in distribution of the maxima, Statistica Neerlandica 36, 31-35.