# Meaning of rate of convergence in central limit theorems

Tags: probability-theory

In central limit theorems, we have the following conclusion
$$
\sqrt{n}\bigg(\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\bigg) - \mu\bigg)\ \xrightarrow{d}\ \mathcal{N}(0,\;\sigma^2). 
$$

[Some book](http://books.google.com/books?id=f66OIvvkKnAC&lpg=PA535&ots=Ajxt_cMw_3&dq=Informally,%20it%20implies%20that%20the%20probabilistic%20rate%20at%20which&pg=PA535#v=onepage&q&f=false) says

> Informally, it implies that the probabilistic rate at which
>   $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ approaches $\mu$ is $1/\sqrt{n}$. That
>   is,  $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ must decay at a rate  $1/\sqrt{n}$
>   to balance the  $\sqrt{n}$ "blow-up" factor  and yield a well-behaved
>   random vector  with the distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\;\sigma^2)$
>   (i.e., well-behaved in the sense of being neither degenerate $0$ nor
>   $\infty$ in magnitude).

I was wondering how the rate of convergence is formally stated in this probabilistic setting?

[A related but more general question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109706/definition-of-rate-of-convergence-for-a-sequence-of-measurable-mappings) was asked a while ago.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I think what the author may mean is that the scale parameter (standard deviation or interquartile range or whatever---take your pick) is $\mathbb{O}(\sqrt{n})$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

That the population mean $m=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i$ "decays at a rate $1/\sqrt{n}$" does not make much sense to me, what "decays"  is the difference $d=m - \mu$. A little more formally, in the context of CLT, the difference converges to zero in quadratic sense: its variance tends to zero, and hence also its standard deviation. And it's staightforward to show that the standard deviation tends to zero as $1/\sqrt{n}$ (which justifies the first sentence of your quote).

$$\sigma^2_d=\sigma^2_m= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_i \sigma^2_{x_i}= \frac{\sigma_x^2}{n}$$

$$ \sigma_d = \frac{\sigma_x}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Then, we multiply $d$ by $\sqrt{n}$ so that its variance does not vanish (sort of a normalization).